# How to integrate Meetup.com calendar into a Wordpress Website with OAuth2?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, meetup

How to integrate Meetup.com Calendar into your Wordpress Website with OAuth2?

Does anyone know how to integrate Meetup.com into a Wordpress Website? In the past I've been using the API:

> https://api.meetup.com/self/calendar?photo-host=public&page=20&sig_id=xxxx&sig=xxxxxxx

But with Meetup.com restricting the use of API and replacing it with OAuth2 does anyone know what's the alternative?

I expect the output to be :

```
[{"created":1560425085000,"duration":7200000,"id":"262283493","name":"London DevOps #45","rsvp_limit":280,"date_in_series_pattern":false,"status":"upcoming","time":1562263200000,"local_date":"2019-07-04","local_time":"19:00","updated":1562150853000,"utc_offset":3600000,"waitlist_count":0,"yes_rsvp_count":240,"venue":{"id":26041493,"name":"Babylon Health","lat":51.49301528930664,"lon":-0.16721400618553162,"repinned":true,"address_1":"60 Sloane
```

but at the moment I receive:

`{"errors":[{"code":"auth_fail","message":"Invalid csrf credentials"}]}`